# Specify starting number when renaming multiple files

Tags: filemanager, batch-rename

I would like to rename multiple files with automatic numbering order. I can do this where the numbering starts at 0 (see screenshot) but I would like to specify the starting number. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Automatic Numbering Order]

Comment: What tool is that?

Comment: I don't know. Its from the blue file cabinet icon on the desktop. When I right-click on the icon and select Show Details, Ubuntu Software displays a dialog that says "No Application Found"

Comment: As much as I know standart Files app is not capable of it. If you want you can download Thunar Bulk Rename from Ubuntu Software. It supports a lot of auto rename methods including the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thunar Bulk Rename works. Thanks for the tip. You can make this the answer if you like.

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thunar Bulk Rename utility from Ubuntu Software. It supports a lot of bulk rename options including the one you mentioned.